# Increment variables within a method?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to build a rock, paper, scissors game. Could someone please tell me or point me in the right direction of where I'm going wrong with this code?

I want the `players_score` and `cpu_score` variables to increment by `1` each time either one wins a round.

```
choice = ["rock", "paper", "Scissors"]

 players_score = 0 
 cpu_score = 0


def win_lose(a,b,c,d)

    if a == "rock" && b == "scissors"
        c+=1
        puts "YOU WIN!!"

    elsif a == "scissors" && b == "rock"
        d+=1
        puts "YOU LOSE!!"

    elsif a =="paper" && b == "rock"
        c+=1
        puts "YOU WIN!!"

    elsif a =="rock" && b == "paper"
        d+=1
        puts "YOU LOSE!!"

    elsif a == "scissors" && b == "paper"
         c+=1
        puts "YOU WIN!!"

    elsif a == "paper" && b == "scissors"
        d+=1
        puts "YOU LOSE!!"

    else a == b
        puts "Its a Draw this time!!"
    end

end

while players_score < 2 && cpu_score < 2


    print "Lets play. Plese choose rock, paper or scissors: "
    players = gets.chomp.downcase
    puts "You have #{players}"

    cpu = choice.sample.downcase
    puts "Computer has #{cpu}"

    win_lose(players, cpu, players_score, cpu_score)
    puts "scores are player #{players_score} , cpu #{cpu_score}"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return a value from `win_lose`, and use that to determine increment the variable, e.g.:

```
def win_lose(a,b,c,d)
    if a == "rock" && b == "scissors"
        c+=1
        winner = 'player'
    elsif a == "scissors" && b == "rock"
        d+=1
        winner = 'computer'
    # [.. etc ..]
    else a == b
        winner = 'draw'
    end

    return winner
end

player_score = 0
cpu_score = 0
choice = ["rock", "paper", "Scissors"]

while players_score < 2 && cpu_score < 2
    print "Lets play. Plese choose rock, paper or scissors: "
    players = gets.chomp.downcase
    puts "You have #{players}"

    cpu = choice.sample.downcase
    puts "Computer has #{cpu}"

    winner = win_lose(players, cpu, players_score, cpu_score)
    if winner == 'player'
        player_score += 1
        puts "YOU WIN!!"
    elsif winner == 'computer'
        cpu_score += 1
        puts "YOU LOSE!!"
    else
        puts "It's a draw"
    end

    puts "scores are player #{players_score} , cpu #{cpu_score}"
end
```

As you can see, this also allows you to not repeat the same "YOU WIN!!" sentence over and over again. I moved that outside the `win_lose` function so that this function does only *one* thing: determine the winner or loser, rather than *two* things: determine the winner or loser, *and* inform them of this.

This distinction is perhaps not important for such a small program, but as your programs grow it will be critical to keep your program understandable.